# How to use Next.js router.push to dynamic api route with Formik, getting 404 (Not found) error

Tags: next.js, formik, dynamic-routing

I'm using the auth0 [nextjs-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0) library to handle signup and authentication for a next.js app. I'm also using [Formik](https://github.com/formik/formik) to handle input data and validation. I'd like to have an email address be submitted via Formik to a Next.js api route.

When I use Nextjs's `useRouter` hook to navigate via `router.push` to the api route, it works as expected, so my data is passed to the api route and nextjs-auth0 redirects the user as expected. However, before redirecting the browser console flashes the following error:

[image]

Should I just ignore this error? Is it possible that `router.push` is for client-side redirects only I'm trying to navigate to an api route, which is not how it should be done? Note, my `/signup` api route uses the auth0-nextjs code and redirects the user to auth0's authentication page. Relevant code below.

Signup api route:

```
import auth0 from "../../../lib/auth0"

export default async function signup(req, res) {

    const {
        query: { pid },
    } = req


    try {
        await auth0.handleLogin(req, res, {
            authParams: {
                initialScreen: "signup",
                login_hint: pid
            },
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message)
    }
}
```

Import of useRouter hook:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
```

Validation function for Formik:

```
    function validateEmail(value) {
        let error;
        let re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/

        if (!value) {
            error = "Email is required"
        } else if (!re.test(value)) {
            error = "Please use a valid email"
        }

        return error
    }
```

Handler function for Formik submit:

```
    const handleFormikSubmit = async (values, actions) => {
        router.push('/api/signup/[...pid]', `/api/signup/${values.email}`)
        actions.setSubmitting(false)
    }
```

Formik component (note, using the <Button component is a [Chakra-ui](https://chakra-ui.com/) component):

```
                                <Formik
                                    initialValues={{ email: "" }}
                                    onSubmit={handleFormikSubmit}
                                >
                                    {(props) => (
                                        <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                                            <Field type="email" name="email" validate={validateEmail}>
                                                {({ field, form }) => (
                                                    <FormControl
                                                        isInvalid={
                                                            form.errors.email &&
                                                            form.touched.email
                                                        }
                                                    >
                                                        <Input
                                                            {...field}
                                                            id="email"
                                                            placeholder="Your email address..."
                                                        />
                                                        <FormErrorMessage>
                                                            {form.errors.email}
                                                        </FormErrorMessage>
                                                    </FormControl>
                                                )}
                                            </Field>
                                            <Button
                                                variantColor="orangish"
                                                width="100%"
                                                mt={2}
                                                className="checkout-style-background"
                                                isLoading={props.isSubmitting}
                                                type="submit"
                                            >
                                                Sign up to get started for $1
                                            </Button>
                                        </form>
                                    )}
                                </Formik>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next/router` is used for client-side transitions between **local pages** whenever it's possible. An API route is always executed on a server side, so you can't perform a client-side navigation to it.

That being said, `next/router` is not useful if you want to redirect to an API route or another website.

Instead, you can use `window.location.replace()` to redirect a user to the API route.

Comment: This seems to work, and now the 404 error disappeared. I replaced the following
router.push('/api/signup/[pid]', `/api/signup/${values.email}`)

with:

window.location.replace(`/api/signup/${values.email}`)

Now using the window.location.replace() method, when on the auth0 login page I have to hit the back button twice to get back to the app on my servers. Before it was only once. Any idea on how to immediately go back to my app with only one click?
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @RancheroBeans, I'm not sure but can try `window.location.href = /api/signup/${values.email}` instead

Comment: you're right and this works perfectly. I can now return to my app using one back press. One slight clarification is that I had to include the /api/signup/${values.email} part in backticks. I'll try to write it here but not sure if the formatting will get messed up:

        `window.location.href = `/api/signup/${values.email}``

Comment: Yup, formatting gets messed up, so I'll indicate a backtick with [backtick] instead:
        `window.location.href = [backtick]/api/signup/${values.email}[backtick]`

Answer (score 2):

The usage of dynamic route is [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#usage). It can be used like the below. First one looks better.

```
import Router from 'next/router'

  ...

Router.push('/post/[pid]', '/post/abc')
```

or

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

  ...

const router = useRouter()

  ...

router.push('/post/[pid]', '/post/abc')
```